# Hibernate validator REGEX pattern not working

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-validator

I am using hibernate validation to validate entities i receive from requests in my Quarkus REST API. I am trying to add quick and simple password validation for creating users by using an `@Pattern` annotation for the *password* field of the `User` entity. It looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User extends BaseEntity {
    public static final int MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH = 8;
    public static final int MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH = 20;
    public static final String PASSWORD_PATTERN = 
        "^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#&()–[{}]:;',?/*~$^+=<>]).{8,20}$";
    
    // other fields...

    @Length(min = MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH, max = MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH)
    @NotBlank(message = "The password field cannot be empty or blank.")
    @Pattern(regexp = PASSWORD_PATTERN, message = "The given password does not match the rules.")
    @Column(name = "password", length = 256, nullable = false)
    private String password;

    //get/set...
}
```

So the REGEX pattern i use is:

```
^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#&()–[{}]:;',?/*~$^+=<>]).{8,20}$
```

Which apparently corresponds to:

- At least one digit
- At least one lower case char
- At least one upper case char
- At least one special char (!@#&()–[{}]:;',?/*~$^+=<>)
- Between 8 and 20 characters long

This works perfectly fine on https://regex101.com/ for Java REGEX engine with the following test password:

> W4schb43r1?!

[image]

However, **hibernate validator throws an error in my endpoint for the same password as it apparently does not match the given pattern**. Why does hibernate validator not match the passwords correctly?

(Parsed response triggered by hibernate ConstrainViolationException):

```
{
  "title": "Constraint Violation",
  "status": 400,
  "violations": [
    {
      "field": "password",
      "message": "The given password does not match the rules."
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hey, I've tested your pattern with a bare Hibernate Validator, and it seems to work fine. Could you create a small reproducer of a problem you are encountering? You could report it either to https://hibernate.atlassian.net/jira/software/c/projects/HV/issues or to https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues; thanks.

Comment: @mark_o Please see my response to this post, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

My bad guys, i found the issue. It was not Hibernate Validator malfunctioning. The exception was caused when the entity got persisted, not when it was parsed and evaluated before the REST endpoint. I changed the password field content before persisting it in the endpoint, and that new value did not match the REGEX.

I was not aware that annotated hibernate validation is also performed before persistence (with entityManager.persist()). I only saw it as something that happens during parsing, for some odd reason. So it was my fault.

Thanks @mark_o for taking your time regardless!